# How can we write \mathcal{a letter} as a subscript

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I wish to write `T` in the subscript of `\rho` as

```
\rho_{\raisebox{-2pt}{\tiny T}}
```

But the desired case is: writing the `T` in the format of `\mathcal`. When I write

```
\rho_{\raisebox{-2pt}{\tiny \mathcal{T}}}
```

TeXStudio does not render it in a correct way!

How can I reach this goal?

Comment: your question is not clear. according to tile one should expect that you looking for `$\rho_{\mathcal{T}}$` or `\rho_{\mathcal{T}}^{}$`. both works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument of `\raisebox` is considered text mode, you have to put `$ $` around `\mathcal{T}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
   $\rho_{\raisebox{-2pt}{\tiny $\mathcal{T}$}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer, however i wonder what is wrong with `\rho_{\mathcal{T}}^{}$` as i wrote in my comment?

Comment: @Zarko I didn't see your comment, I only corrected the error of the OP...

Comment: i know, i just wonder :-). your answer is correct (+1) :-)

Answer (score 5):

i wonder why you not use simple

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}

\begin{document}
 text  $\rho_{\mathcal{T}}$, text $\rho_{\mathcal{T}}^{}$
\end{document}
```

is something wrong with this?

[image]

according to rules how to set indices, i don't see what is wrong with this standard way of writing them.